# Google Analytics - Demographics aren't working

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Good Morning,

I've updated my customers Google Analytic's account to use the **latest version** of the tracking code. Also I've amended the setting **'Enable Demographics and Interest Reports'** to enabled.

For the past 3-4 days no information has come through despite visitors to the website.

Please can you advise me on which this isn't working...

The website is: http://www.fellpromotions.co.uk/

I look forward to hearing from you.

Kind Regards,

Shaun 
https://twitter.com/shaunswales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demographics is not yet supported in Universal Analytics.

> The dc.js JavaScript library is not supported in Universal Analytics
>   during this phase. Users who need the following related features
>   should wait until Phase 3 to upgrade: Remarketing Google Display
>   Network Impression Reporting DoubleClick Campaign Manager Reporting
>   Google Analytics Demographics and Interests Reports

[(From the UA upgrade center)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/)

Comment: I've got a number of websites that seem to be collecting this data fine, could you please advise me on how I can resolve this?

Comment: You can't really - you'd have to return to the old trackingcode and replace ga.hs with dc.js, only you cannot downgrade an account if it is already transferred to universal analytics.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

How long until the update/phase is released?

Comment: As (strangely enough) the answer has just now been accepted I'd like to point out that this is no longer correct. Demographics can be enabled in the property settings.